# The BigQuery software is showing that I have not put parenthesis while using nested query although I have put parenthesis as given in the code

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

This is what is displayed when I tried to execute the SQL statements:

> Each function argument is an expression, not a query; to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression at [3:1]

```
select station_id, name, number_of_rides
    (
    select start_station_id, count(*) as number_of_rides
    from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
    group by start_station_id
    ) 
from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
inner join `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
on station_id=start_station_id
order by numer_of_rides desc
```

Comment: Why have you written `select ..., **column** **subquery**` &  what do you think it means, justified by documentation? Did you mean to put a comma between them? What did your research show "[3:1]" means? What did your research show about the error message? PS [mre] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended the subquery of the same table that's in your additional FROM statement to be core table?

So something like this should work:

```
select station_id,name,number_of_rides
from (
  select
  start_station_id,count(*) as number_of_rides
  from 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
  group by 
  start_station_id
) a
inner join
`bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` on station_id=start_station_id
order by number_of_rides desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A comma is missing, have it as :

select station_id,name,number_of_rides,

Comment: That doesn't solve the problems. Anyway it's not clear what the query should accomplish. Debug questions without a [mre] should be closed, not answered. [ask] [answer] [Help]